# Django: What do I need to do to get the csv file to actually load into the model?

Tags: python, django, csv

I am having a problem getting my upload.html to be fully functional. The html page shows okay and I can even select an csv file for upload. It does not do anything when clicking on the "Add data" button. What do I need to do to get the csv file to actually load into the model. Below is the code for upload.html shown below:

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap5 %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Please select csv file for upload</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-control" >
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}
    
    </form>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add data</button>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is the forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Csv
 
class CsvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Csv
        fields = ('file_name',)
```

Below is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CsvForm
from .models import Csv
import csv
 
def upload_file_view(request):
 
    form = CsvForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = CsvForm()
        obj = Csv.objects.get(activated=False)
        with open(obj.file_name.path, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                # this is not working yet.
                print(row)
        obj.activated=True
        obj.save()
 
    context = {'form': form,}
    return render(request, 'csvs/upload.html', context)
```

below is the models.py

```
from django.db import models
 
class Csv(models.Model):
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs/', max_length=100)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return "File id: {}".format(self.id)
```

I don't understand the code completely. Can the csv be located in any directory when selecting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Upload.html file has the button outside the  block. So it has to change to inside the form tag like below.

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap5 %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Please select csv file for upload</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-control" >
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add data</button>
    </form>
    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```